# CKFetchRecordChangesOperation returns no records

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift, cloudkit

CKFetchRecordChangesOperation in the simplified method below does not return any records. 
I call it with a nil, to initially get all the records, but it only returns the server token.
However, if I use CKQuery I get all the records correctly.

What am I missing?

```
 func fetchChangedRecords(token :CKServerChangeToken?) {

    println("\(__FUNCTION__) token: \(token)")

    let zoneID = CKRecordZoneID(zoneName: kMyZone, ownerName: CKOwnerDefaultName)
    var op = CKFetchRecordChangesOperation(recordZoneID: zoneID, previousServerChangeToken: token)

    op.recordChangedBlock = {
        record in
        println("\(__FUNCTION__) record \(record)")
    }

    op.recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock = {
        recordID in
        println("\(__FUNCTION__) record \(recordID)")

    }

    op.fetchRecordChangesCompletionBlock = {
        serverChangeToken, clientChangeToken, error in

        println("\(__FUNCTION__) server token  \(serverChangeToken), clientChangeToken \(clientChangeToken)")

        if let err = error {
            println("\(__FUNCTION__) Error: \(err)")
        }

         if op.moreComing {
            println("\(__FUNCTION__) moreComing")
            self.fetchChangedRecords(serverChangeToken)
        }
    }

    println("\(__FUNCTION__) op \(op)")

    privateDB.addOperation(op)
}
```

EDIT:

So, I updated the code with a an additional method call based on the value of moreComing. This below is what's printed. I also checked that the zone is there.

moreComing does not seem to be set.

```
fetchChangedRecords token: nil 
fetchChangedRecords op <CKFetchRecordChangesOperation: 0x16dd3e30; operationID=14A302B7-2718-4E05-97C7-B28EC01ED75B> 
fetchChangedRecords server token  <CKServerChangeToken: 0x16ddfd80; data=AQAAAAAAAAACf/////////+p9bdUdAhLUK36bhza7+4g>, clientChangeToken nil
```

Just to show that the zone is there.

```
zone fetching succeeded [<CKRecordZone: 0x16dda330; zoneID=MyZone:__defaultOwner__, capabilities=(Atomic,Sync)>, <CKRecordZone: 0x16d5bb70; zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__, capabilities=(none)>]
```

Comment: The code looks correct to me. Can you attach the output of running this code? If `moreComing == YES` in the completion block you need to keep calling `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` with an updated change token until `moreComing == NO`

Comment: That's very odd. Would you mind reproducing this with logging enabled and either filing a radar or posting the logs somewhere? Make sure to run both the `CKFetchChangesOperation` that isn't returning results and the `CKQueryOperation` that is returning results. Instructions on enabling and grabbing logs can be found at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/icloud/#icloud-drive

Comment: Thanks very much for the help pointers. It turns out that (and I am quite embarrassed to admit this) the issue was simply that all my records where initially put into the default zone, which I then forgot and was trying to get the changed ones from the custom zone.

Comment: It happens. Good to hear everything works!

Comment: if you have created lots of records and deleted them, the initial batch may be empty.

Using moreComing ensures you get all the current records, over a few batches if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` is deprecated.  I think it may have been replaced by `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation` and `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation`?  `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation` is discussed in [2016 WWDC Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/231/), but it's in the context of shared databases.